# Object msg send error coming

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I am trying to do the following

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
if(textView == txtYourTip){
    if([txtYourTip.text length] < 100){
        strTip = txtYourTip.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",strTip);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",strTip);
        txtYourTip.text = strTip;
    }}
```

Application crashes when controls goes to else part. **strTip** is of type NSString.

viewDidLoad contains

```
    txtYourTip = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 80, 290, 80)];
[txtYourTip.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[txtYourTip setDelegate:self];
[txtYourTip setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
txtYourTip.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
[txtYourTip.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[contentView addSubview:txtYourTip];
```

strTip = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

Comment: Where are strTip and txtYourTip declared? Are you sure they're not nil and that their pointers are valid when you get to the else?

Comment: both are declared in .h file and and I set strTip = @"" in viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you post the source for viewDidLoad? Or anything else?

Comment: txtYourTip = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 80, 290, 80)];
 [txtYourTip.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
 [txtYourTip setDelegate:self];
 [txtYourTip setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
 txtYourTip.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
 [txtYourTip.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
 [contentView addSubview:txtYourTip];
strTip = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

Comment: Maybe if you add the whole class... but if you do, please update your question - don't add it here in the comments.

Comment: Actually it's working fine otherwise. Only when I try to access strTip in else part, I get a crash.

Comment: In the if you assign a new value to strtip, so it's normal that it wouldn't crash there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the strTip = @"" in viewDidLoad like you said I think that is the reason.
Allocating a NSString with @"a text" is making it autoreleased. So at some point the data is released but the pointers points to it. When you try to display it you have an exception.

Try this in your viewDidLoad :
`strTip = [[NSString alloc] init];`
or

```
strTip = @"";
[strTip retain];
```

Either one should work and will need a :

```
[strTip release];
strTip = nil;
```

in the view viewDidUnload so you don't leak

Comment: Even though he said @"", you can see from his code that he's actually assigning `[[NSMutableString alloc] init];` to `strTip`.

Comment: I noticed, but since he told us two different thing, in case the second one was the one used. It was worth to try :)